# PHP protected and private properties?

Tags: php, object, private, protected

I have a class in PHP that upon an instance being created takes an instance of itself as an argument. A mock of the class is below.

```
abstract class AAA {

    protected $_a;
    protected $_b;

    public function __construct($a, $b) {

         $this->_a = $a;
         $this->_b = $b;
    }
}

class BBB extends AAA {

    private $_aaa;

    public function __construct($a, $b, AAA $aaa) {

        parent::__construct($a, $b);
        $this->_aaa = $aaa;
    }
}
```

Within a method of `BBB` I have full access to the protected properties of `$aaa`. An example of this is below.

```
# BBB method
public function getAAAprotected() {

    return array(
        '_a' => $this->_aaa->_a,
        '_b' => $this->_aaa->_b,
    );
}
```

I am confused as to how this can be. My understanding of `protected` properties were that they can only be accessed by extended classes within that instance or have I been wrong all of this time.

Could someone please explain, or give direction, so that I can fully understand when or not a `protected`/`private` method/function are just that?

Comment: Haha a downvote seriously? Why do people who take a question with a seemlessly easy answer for themselves, as a pointless question.

Comment: Either I need sleep or you just answered your own question

Comment: I was unsure how the visibility of properties/methods within a class fundamentally works. I don't think I answered that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and
>   protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is
>   because the implementation specific details are already known when
>   inside those objects.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects

Comment: Thank you very much. Great help. Was of great help to me and I'm sure it will be to others.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: 3 minutes left until I can. Thanks again for helping.